# error message: You are not connected to the facebook account that this application is registered to

Tags: 7

I have configured the fbconnect.  I put the ID and secret, I have installed the library.  When I active the block doesn't show nothing.  It's a white block.

When I am going to "App Settings" in the configuration of module appears the next message:

"You are not connected to the facebook account that this application is registered to"

What's happening?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you set up the domain correctly on the facebook end?  if facebook thinks you are at www.foo.com and you connect from www.bar.com it sometimes isn't happy.

Comment: If I try this module in a development site is it possible that this message appears?

Comment: when I've done some fb app stuff on development boxes with different domains from production I've found it easier to just create an app specifically for them and then when going production, changing over.  otherwise, I've stumbled over all sorts of gotchas like this.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've created an app for the development site with my personal facebook account and the url I put in the app is the same url I put in the field "connect url" and continue the message.

Comment: Grr.  You've taken care of the most obvious problem.  Unfortunately now you'll have to dig into it more and go through all of the various facebook settings to make sure everything is exactly right.

Comment: Hi, The message doesn't appear, the empty block is by the theme.  Thanks a lot for your help.  Now I am reviewing as works the "connect" button.  Your help was useful for me.  It's necessary configurate correctly the domain.

Comment: Hi.  I want you to ask something about the Facebook Connect.  The button "Connect" appears in the block if the block is in garland but the same block in a custom theme the button "connect" is not shown.  Do you have any idea?  thanks-

Comment: sorry no, gotta look at the various sources to see what might be differnt ;(

Comment: Hello.  I'm here again.  Do you have any idea why the option "invite friends from fb" in the connect module appears a white screen?  Excuse me for my poor english.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: a white screen usually means a php or other error.  check your logs and if so it will tell you what file is giving problems

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your answer.  I have reviewed the logs and not reports any error.  http://screencast.com/t/YbsAzYQx.  Thanks again for your answers and your help.

Comment: oh, I thought you meant an ENTIRE white screen.  too much could be going on with just a portion of it not working.  at this point you'll need to go into the html of the page and see when it stopped and then backtrack from there.  alas, that's not something that can be remotely diagnosed.